# How to change button style generated by jinja loop.with bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I have question on which I can not find answer. I have code that through the loop generate me list of buttons. Button clicked should change its style (background color solid). Html code is made with bootstrap. What can be done to change style of clicked button, when in code structure I have only one link? Below please find fragment of code:

```
{% for list in lists %} 

<a href="{{ url_for('homepage', list_type=list) }}"  
class="btn btn-fill-skew btn-outline-primary">{{list|replace("_", " ")}}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the value of selected list from the view function, let's call it `active_list`. Then you can test during the loop whether the current item is the selected one:

```
{% for list in lists %} 

<a href="{{ url_for('homepage', list_type=list) }}"  
   class="btn btn-fill-skew {% if list == selected_list %}btn-primary{% else %}btn-outline-primary{% endif %}">
       {{list|replace("_", " ")}}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Here we add the `btn-primary` class for the selected list instead of `btn-outline-primary`, so it will become filled with the primary color.

Comment: Thank you Dauros. This is what I needed!